# How do I create a copy of a record in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a action that creates a copy of the checked object.

My action so far:

```
  def create_multiple
    @webhost = Webhost.find(params[:webhost_ids])
    @webhost.each do |webhost|
    Webhost.new(:webhost)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(:admin_webhosts, :notice => 'Konkurrancerne er nu slettet') }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
end
```

The action renders but no new webhost copy is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if that works (notice the `create` instead of `new`, since `new` by itself won't save it):

```
def create_multiple
    @webhost = Webhost.find(params[:webhost_ids])
    @webhost.each do |webhost|
    Webhost.create(webhost.attributes)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(:admin_webhosts, :notice => 'Konkurrancerne er nu slettet') }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'new' method only instantiates a new object. It doesn't persist the object to your database (or whatever). You'll either have to call save on that object, or you could do

```
def create_multiple
    @webhost = Webhost.find(params[:webhost_ids])
    @webhost.each do |webhost|
    Webhost.create(webhost.attributes)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(:admin_webhosts, :notice => 'Konkurrancerne er nu slettet') }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
end
```

Calling create will instantiate a new object and save it (as long as it passes any validations).

Comment: Now it creates a new webhost, but with no data, :webhost_ids is the ID of the checked webhosts